# How to activate Bluetooth on HP 15 notebook, using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, hp

Please help. I cant activate Bluetooth on my HP laptop.

Problem - no Bluetooth adapters found. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, Intel Celeron, HP 15 Notebook.

I already installed the Bluetooth packages and even used the command: **`rfkill unblock bluetooth`** under startup applications but to no avail.

Please help me find a way out. Thanks already for your answers ..

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a hardware switch to turn it on, I feel that the only solution is via Windows because sometimes hardware deactivated in Windows does not appear on other OS.

In my case I had to install Windows 7 on new created partition (10 GB), install all neccesery drivers for Bluetooth and turn it on there. Then reboot to Ubuntu to check if the Bluetooth Adapter is found. Also check for BIOS settings, maybe the Bluetooth is turned off from Bios?

BEWARE: Check the solutions for Windows/Ubuntu dual boot before proceeding! It is not as simple as it looks like, better have your Ubuntu CD prepared!